# BE formatted dates not imported correctly (or not at all)

Tags: plugin-feedme

I've also raised this question / issue at https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe/issues/255 but this forum might be a better a place as I'm unsure if it is a bug actually

FeedMe uses date_parse to parse dates in an inbound feed. This usually works out great, the problem I have now is a certain XML-feed is using the Belgian date format (dd/mm/yyyy). I'm unable to change that unfortunately.

2 issues:

- in case the dd is > 12, the import does not process the date
- when dd <= 12, it does import them but for some reason it has an -2h offset. Probably some timezone issue, as the timezone is set to Europe/Brusssels, which is CET+2h

Is there a way to

- preparse the dates somehow, to make sure the dates are available in a format that can be understood at all time (eg. yyyy-mm-dd)?
- set the timezone somehow, so the feedme / craft knows the dates are being presented in CET+2h already?

---

**EDITED**

The timezone issue (second bullet) appears to be a known issue, see https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe/commit/a923b67350341dcb17a628376bbb9ab4aa373780 
This commit did not make it to a release yet (I'm using the most recent one 2.0.7 that doesn't contain this bug fix), if you use the codebase that is currently on the master branch this issue is fixed! 
This leaves me with just 1 to go!

Comment: Could be related to your users preferred locale. Craft uses that to format the dates used in the CP area, and maybe Feedme just uses the craft date format checker? I'm not sure though...  You can switch your preferred locale from your profile.

Comment: Feedme runs from a cronjob and doesn't require any UI to be started.  It appears to be an issue that is already fixed in the master branch, but did not make it yet to a regular release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After being in contact with the developer both issues are solved. If you have a similar issue use the latest codebase on the master branch (not the 2.0.7 as that version doesn't have the fixes yet)

- for the first issue (date format problem) there is an additional functionality available that allows you to predefine what the layout is of the date field you're trying to import

[image]

- second issue (the date offset problem) was a bug and has been fixed

The most recent codebase can be found here: https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe/archive/master.zip

A big thanks to [Josh Crawford](https://github.com/engram-design) for helping out that fast!